# iPod does not start

Tags: ipod

i have an iPod here ( i do not know the generation. it has 60GB and supports video. it is white and comparatively thick. thicker than iPhone for sure. )

It has not been used for a long time. When i begin to load it, the screen stays black and the Apple Logo shows up. The apple logo will stay and the screen wont change. The iPod wont start. If i remove the cable, the apple logo wont disappear until the battery is empty again. The iPod wont show up in iTunes.

I did toggel "Hold" on and off.
I tried selecting "Select" + "Menu". As far as i have read, the Apple logo should show up, which i cannot confirm, since the Apple logo is showing the whole time. The screen wont flash. It stays the same. I pressed well over 30 seconds to make sure. Nothing happens.

I also tried going into diagnostic mode by selecting "Select" + "Rewind", which has no effect. The Apple logo wont show in reverse.

The screen stays the same for the whole time.
Anyone has any tips left?

Comment: This question should be moved to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you reset the iPod as per [How to reset iPod](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1320)? Keeping in mind:

> If you are having difficulty resetting your iPod, set it on a flat surface. Make sure the finger pressing the Select button is not touching any part of the click wheel. Also make sure that you are pressing the Menu button toward the outside of the click wheel, and not near the center.

If you have reset it you need to get it into [Disk Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1363). If it doesn't work or respond keep trying and it just [might](http://www.ipodwizard.net/showthread.php?t=33807).

Comment: i am sure that i exactly repeated the steps described in the document. i have to mention, that the preconditions are not exactly met, because the Apple logo is already displaying at the begin of the process. So i cannot verify that the process is working correctly, since it should indicate working correctly by displaying the apple logo a few seconds after pressing "Select" + "Menu"

Comment: alright i will try it for an hour or so and then report back later =)

Answer (score 0):

Put your iPod in a sack of uncoocked rice and leave it for 24 to 48 hrs. Rice has excellent moisture soaking capability and will soak your iPod dry.
This method is more suited if your iPod is wet somehow or moisture is causing the start failure.

There's no harm trying this of course, it [has worked miracles for some iPods](http://www.labnol.org/gadgets/ipod/drop-mobile-phone-ipod-water-fix-iphone/2707/).

Comment: would there be a reason to try this if the iPod was not in water? ( will try if there dont come up any other tips

Comment: well, since ur iPod was not used for a long time, I'm assuming some moisture effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold the iPod to your ear, do you hear the hard drive clicking, or spinning up and down over and over?  If so, the drive might be the cause of the hang.